# Convert quarter period data to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with quarter values assigned to some stocks data and it looks like this:

```
fiscalDateQuarter
2015Q1
2015Q2
2015Q3
2015Q4
2016Q1
```

the dtype for this columns is `period[Q-DEC]` . If I run pd.to_datetime(df["fiscalDateQuarter"]), I get the following error `TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid.`

Is there any way I can convert this to a datetime or period format showing the first day of the first month in the quarter?

For example, where the value is `2015Q1` I want to create a new column that says `2015-01-01`. Where the value is `2015Q2` I want the new value to show `2015-04-01` and so on.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Did you try `pd.to_datetime(df["fiscalDateQuarter"])` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes I did and it returns an error, hence why I'm asking for help. I don't really know how to go about it

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what error you've got? Because when I run `pd.to_datetime(df["fiscalDateQuarter"])` it works.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I updated the question with the dtype of the column and the error I get

Comment: Try `df["fiscalDateQuarter"].astype("datetime64[M]")`

Comment: @AndrejKesely still doesn't work, I get the following error: Cannot cast PeriodArray to dtype datetime64[M]

Comment: Maybe `pd.to_datetime(df["fiscalDateQuarter"].astype(str))` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely the last one worked perfectly, thanks a lot!